# Cancel a Keypress Event in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, keypress

I want to cancel a keypress event for a long textbox so that the character newly pressed by the user is not entered in the textbox

```
longBox_1.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
        String Valid="1234567890";
        if (!Valid.contains(String.valueOf(event.getCharCode()))) {
            // the code to cancel the event to be placed here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your longBox_1 is a private member of your class, or a final var, the code to cancel the event is :

```
longBox_1.cancelKey();
```

Otherwise you can cast the source of the event, if you are sure it correspond to the TextBox :

```
((TextBox)event.getSource()).cancelKey();
```

Here is the doc for cancelKey :

> If a keyboard event is currently being
>   handled on this text box, calling this
>   method will suppress it. This allows
>   listeners to easily filter keyboard
>   input