# GWT KeyPress filter

Tags: java, gwt, filter, keypress

How do you go about creating KeyPress filter that would enforce only digits as input in text field. Something like this here:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_keypress_filter

As added anoyence is there a way of doing this in uiBinder xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code to do that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872009/cancel-a-keypress-event-in-gwt).

In your uiBinder file, define your TextBox item.

```
<g:TextBox uifield='textBox'/>
```

In your class, you can either add the KeyPressHandler directly, like :

```
textBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            if (!"0123456789".contains(String.valueOf(event.getCharCode()))) {
                textBox.cancelKey();
            }
        }

    });
```

Or you can use the @UiHandler annotation like so:

```
@UiHandler("testBox")
public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
    if (!"0123456789".contains(String.valueOf(event.getCharCode()))) {
        textBox.cancelKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: With this way we cannot use function keys like backspace, Home, End