# GWT cancel a keypress event in a RichTextBox

Tags: events, gwt, richtextbox, keypress

I would like to cancel a particular keypress event in a RichTextBox.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872009/cancel-a-keypress-event-in-gwt) it is described how to do it in a regular *TextBox*, but it doesn't work in a *RichTextArea* because it doesn't have the cancelKey() method.

Here's my code:

```
   RichTextArea richTextArea = new RichTextArea();
   ...
   richTextArea.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                // Here is where I would like to prevent the ENTER key from going to the richTextBox
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what are the key events u want to disable

Comment: He already mentioned in the qtn  that  he wants to cancel keypress event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this working fine for me ...

```
  RichTextArea richTextArea = new RichTextArea();
       richTextArea.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent arg0) {
                if (arg0.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                    arg0.getNativeEvent().preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ how can i disable all keys in my keyboard? :)

Comment: @Naveen just remove the `if` condition :). That prevents all the keypress.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ got it :)